# VirtualBox: How much disk i/o speed gain will I gain if I have fixed-size hdd image?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, io

I am running virtualbox on win7 with a dynamically allocated hard disk image. It seems to consume a lot of CPU and be slow on hdd activity.

I've heard that not choosing a dynamically sized virtual hdd in VirtualBox will be faster than a dynamically allocated one. Does anyone know approximately how much faster it will be? Are we talking 5% or say 80% or something?

In short:
**How much disk i/o speed gain will I gain if I have fixed-size hdd image? Is it worth the effort to bother**

Comment: personally, I wouldn't expect any real improvement at all. the cost of expanding the size of a virtual volume should be negligible compared to the actual (abstracted) IO, unless you are adding huge files to a system that previously only had a small allocation.

Comment: OK thx! I can mark as answer if you write it...